# RecyclerView view doesn't change using background_selector

Tags: android-recyclerview, background

I'm Trying to toggle item background color upon item selection.

I can see it's logic is working yet the background wouldn't change.
The log prints show the selctions indeed work, yet the background not.

From background_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_purple" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

from task_row.xml:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    android:id="@+id/tasksCardView"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

From Adapter code:

```
class MyTasksAdapter (
    val arrayList: ArrayList<Task>,
   
    val selectedItemsList: ArrayList<Task>,
    val deletedItemsList: ArrayList<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyTasksAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

        private var cardView: CardView = itemView.tasksCardView

        private val selectedItems = SparseBooleanArray()
        override fun onClick(view: View) {
            if (selectedItems[adapterPosition, false]) {
                selectedItems.delete(adapterPosition)
                cardView.isSelected = false
                Log.d("Item selected AA", "position: $position")
            }
            else {
                selectedItems.put(adapterPosition, true)
                view.isSelected = true
                Log.d("Item selected BB", "position: $position")
            }
        }

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)

        }
```

Tried also changing cardview to view, but it didn't help either.

```
class MyTasksAdapter (
    val arrayList: ArrayList<Task>,
    val selectedItemsList: ArrayList<Task>,
    val deletedItemsList: ArrayList<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyTasksAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

        //private lateinit var item: ClipData.Item
        private var cardView: CardView = itemView.tasksCardView

        private val selectedItems = SparseBooleanArray()
        override fun onClick(view: View) {
            if (selectedItems[adapterPosition, false]) {
                selectedItems.delete(adapterPosition)
                view.isSelected = false
                Log.d("Item selected AA", "position: $position")
            }
            else {
                selectedItems.put(adapterPosition, true)
                view.isSelected = true
                Log.d("Item selected BB", "position: $position")
            }
        }

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)

        }
```

Appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Try using foreground instead of background.

Comment: foreground Indeed changes now the color of the item as expected (toggle) but I can't see anything inside the items :-(

Comment: use `alpha` property so that the color doesn't completely hide the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now.
Moved it to the relative_layout header: instead of cardview_layout header

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    android:id="@+id/tasksCardView"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        **android:background="@drawable/background_selector"**
        android:padding="16dp">
```